# ANDROID - Reading file from localhost (ERROR)

Tags: android

I have a code which load a textfile from my localhost, i am using xampp, i put my file on xampp folder under htdocs. here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    httpStuff = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);        
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/name.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));           
        String str = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        httpStuff.setText(str);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}}
```

and I got this error. I don't know what's wrong. I have also added permission internet in my androidmanifest.xml file.

```
   10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.name.in.a.textfile/com.example.name.in.a.textfile.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at com.example.name.in.a.textfile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-24 17:17:45.024: E/AndroidRuntime(7544):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is 'this error'? Add this to the `catch (IOException e)` clause: `e.printStackTrace();` and post the logcat's output

Comment: I just update the question. I just did what you said and that was the result in log.

Comment: You problem is **NetworkOnMainThreadException**, change so you don't do your network communication in the Main Thread, but instead implement an AsyncTask for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is shown in this line
`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 10-24 17:07:44.745: E/AndroidRuntime(7143)`

In android, You cannot perform network actions in the main thread, as it may block the UI from updating for more than 5 seconds, causing the app to not respond.

You should do something like this (not tested)
the `try` block should be:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/name.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));           
        String str = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() { 
               httpStuff.setText(str);
           }
        });

    });
t.start();
```

This way you perform the networking on a different thread, but since you need to update the UI once the networking is finished, you need to use `runOnUIThread` because on the UI Thread can update UI components.

Another and possibly better option is the `AsyncTask`
You put your networking tasks in its `doInBackground` method, and update the UI in the `onPostExecute` method, this way you don't need to mess around with thread. basically `AsyncTask` does what I described above. you should look into this, as all networking should be done in different threads than the UI, and `AsyncTask` is a great and easy option.

Answer (score 0):

Seven on and am here with an improved answer because I too have been through this problem

```
private class myStreamReader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String str = "";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(""http://10.0.2.2/name.txt"");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            str = in.readLine();
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //do something here
         httpStuff.setText(str);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

on usage simply call this

```
new.myStreamReader().execute();
```

Comment: you have really saved a lot of lives here

Comment: Ha ha ha Oh I almost thought I had saved a lot of files